# What extra work is needed when compiling Android on real devices

Tags: android

I followed the guide on android.com and compiled the source code. Now it runs well in the emulator. There are some .img files so I think it may be viable to flash them on real devices.

But I see on the guide there is a 4th step, which is to compile some device-specific proprietary files. But my device is not on their list. So what extra work needs to be done if I want to flash the .img files to real devices rather than the emulator? Will the real devices get bricked? Thanks.

Comment: @thinksteep - I think OP is talking about compiling the Android system, not an app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well -- that is the "difficult" part of making a custom ROM for a device.  You need to have a complex understanding of the particular hardware that you're building for, and adjust and update the codebase accordingly.

That said -- a real device will (probably) not get bricked, but you will need to use the recovery image to put a working ROM back on to use the device again.  Make sure you have a rooted device and a decent recovery on it (Clockworkmod)